# Output characteristics of 2N3904 BJT transistor

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

I want to apply the load line analysis to the BJT amplifier that I have built. I can not find the collector characteristic of 2N3904 npn on the data sheet. There are lots of graphs but not collector vs VCE.

Anyone knows where I can find its output characteristics?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "collector characteristic" or "output characteristics"?

Comment: Are you looking for a Vce-Ic graph, like how you see Vds-Id graphs for MOSFETs? I don't think that would be a very useful graph for BJTs.

Comment: If that *is* what you're looking for, I think Figure 2 of the [onsemi datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/pzt3904-d.pdf) (page 5) is the best you're going to get.

Comment: We usually do not use load line analysis, anymore. It was pretty much required with crappy triode vacuum tubes and without Spice or PCs. But we have different tools now. Anyway, can you show us the schematic of your BJT amplifier? This may go a long way in working out (1) how to more directly answer your question using datasheets and/or simulation and (2) how we may suggest an alternate view that is easy and achieves similar (or better) results without the load line charting. But I fear we can't know if such suggestions are helpful without more info from you.

Comment: The load line is quite useful for simple cases. However it's true, in the NXP and ST datasheet there is no output curve family:P The reason is that it's designed as a *switching* transistor, not for linear operation IMHO. Look at the BC548 for most purposes it's supposedly equivalent. Edit: MCC datasheet has the curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$I_{collector}\$ versus \$V_{collector}\$?
Not even the *old* data books show that graph. Seems it is used mostly by students to graphically see how a collector resistor reacts to the transistor's characteristics. Rarely used by engineers.

LTspice includes models for 2N3904, also SST3904. The 2N3904 yields a rather high current gain \$H_{fe}= 300\$. The SST3904 model is a bit less, and seems to jive with my memory of curve-tracing a batch of 2N3904s.

If you need different bias conditions, generate your own graphs using LTspice DCsweep.
[image: LTspice test circuit]
[image: Ic versus Vc for SST3904]

Comment: It's also a good graphical way to see the Early effect. Never actually found myself using it for anything after school, though.

Comment: @glen_geek yes this is exactly what I was looking for. I will simulate it then. Thank you. Do you think for a simple audio amplifier npn BJT is Ok or I should use MOSFETs?

Comment: or just use an opmap?

Comment: @Jack That depends entirely on what you want to do with this amplifier. We can't really answer without knowing more about what your intent is, what kind of load it needs to drive and such.

Comment: As I said, it is an audio amplifier that I am trying to make.